# Cannot assign 'AppDelegate' to 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode9, swxmlhash

I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/ios-remote-push-notifications-in-a-nutshell-d05f5ccac252

But for some reason, I'm getting

> cannot assign 'AppDelegate' to 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate'.

What does that line do? If I comment it out, the rest of the code works and the user is prompted if they want to allow notifications.

```
func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self // line in question
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        (granted, error) in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
        // 1. Check if permission granted
        guard granted else { return }
        // 2. Attempt registration for remote notifications on the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I pasted in the latest version of SWXMLHash and that fixed the issue, but now I get `Value of type 'XMLIndexer' has no member 'flatMap'

Comment: `flatMap` has been deprecated. Using `compactMap` instead

Comment: have you implemented this delegate "UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate" in appdelegate class ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `import` the related `delegate` `(UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate)` in your `AppDelegate` class first like below code.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
```

In your code `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` self doesn't respond to required `delegate` that is why you are getting error message.

Answer (score 3):

Import `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` into your `AppDelegate` Class and it should work fine.